# How to remove Grub2 or Windows bootloader?

Tags: dual-boot, grub2, 18.04, windows-10, bootloader

I was using Windows 10. Then I installed Ubuntu 18.04 LTS as multiboot. Grub2 replaced Windows bootloader.

I wanted Windows bootloader.

So I installed EasyBCD 2.3 on my Windows 10. Created a new Linux entry on it. When I booted I had two entries, but instead of booting to Ubuntu it booted to "grub4dos".

I used "boot repair tool" via live USB. It reinstalled "grub2". But now I have two boot loaders.

Grub2 loads first. Then, when I select Windows 10 from it, Windows boot loader loaded up. I have to select Windows from it to boot into Windows 10.

As I use Windows 10, regularly. I have to go through two boot loaders to get to my Windows 10.

I like to have either Grub2 or Windows bootloader which boots both OS with single click.

Please help.

I use Laptop with single HDD.

[image]

I had tried different options on EasyBCD but every time I end up using my "boot repair live usb" to reinstall Grub2.

Answer (score 0):

**-1- Rewrite Windows 10 Stock BootLoader**
Boot with Win10 install media, got to console and run this

```
bootrec /fixmbr<br>
bootrec /rebuildbcd
```

**-2- Test it**: booting the PC should to to Win10

**-3- Repair Ubuntu Boot** with Ubuntu install media
BootUbuntu from LiveUSB
Get the drive device name with Gparted
Run those commands

```
sudo mount /dev/sdXY /mnt  # Example: sudo mount /dev/sda5 /mnt
sudo grub-install --root-directory=/mnt /dev/sdX # Example: sudo grub-install --root-directory=/mnt /dev/sda
```

See this
https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1581099&p=9884063#post9884063

Comment: These suggestions are valid for older PC's with legacy BIOS, but not for modern ones with EFI based BIOS ! :)